# php how to remove percentage value inside bracket

Tags: php, regex

How to remove the percentage value inside the bracket.

example:

```
<?php
$raw = "orange (43%), blue (2.1) (55%), red yellow (77%), red-blue (80%)";
$remove = preg_replace('/[%]/', '', $raw);
echo $remove;
?>
```

results:

`orange (43), blue (2.1) (55), red yellow (77), red-blue (80)`

What I need is like this:

`orange, blue (2.1), red yellow, red-blue`

Comment: How would you expect that your current regex does this? Try [`\h+\(\d+%\)`](https://regex101.com/r/gQDpKT/1) ([php demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6UosVzBVkEpvygxLz1VQcPEWFVTRyEppxTINtIz1FTQMDUFiRSlpihUpubk5JcraJibQ0V0IeosDFQ1layBRqXm5pelAk0rKEpNjy9KLchJTE7VUNePydCO0YhJ0VaN0dRX11FQB2KQtZrWXKnJGfkKUH3W//8DAA))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\s+\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\)
```

And replace this with `""`. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/L3nSD5/1).

Comment: thank you @Jan, its work perfectly as like what I want to be.

Answer (score 0):

**here you go, works 100%**

```
$raw = "orange (43%), blue (2.1) (55%), red yellow (77%), red-blue (80%)";
$raw = explode(", ", $raw);
for($a = 0; $a <= count($raw) - 1; $a++){
    $test = explode(" ", $raw[$a]);
    
    
    for($b = 0; $b <= count($test) - 1; $b++){
        if(str_contains($test[$b], '%')){
            $test[$b] = '';
        }
    }
    $result[$a] = implode(" ", $test);
    
}
$raw = implode(", ", $result);
echo $raw;
```

Comment: thanks for your answering @HUNAIN AHMED 1002, little bit long coded but work pretty nice. hopefully this question may help other people also.